# Video modal keeps closing when I try to click on video to play HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having an issue implementing video pop up using html/css and bootstrap.

Basically when I click on the link, the modal appears with the video, but the moment I click on the video to play, it closes the modal.

I want it so that the user can play the video and interact with the controls, the moment they click anywhere in the background away from the video, it closes the video.

You can see how it's currently working on our website https://www.metis-online.com/#courses and you will see under 'Explainder Videos' two links that opens up the relevant video models.

HTML:

```
<h5>Explainer Videos</h5>
<p>Check out our videos below taken from one of our recorded webinars to see if this certification is right for you:
<ul class="nobullet">
<li><a style="text-decoration: underline; color:white;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#flitpc-video-1">See what our online course looks like</a></li>   
<li><a style="text-decoration: underline; color:white;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#flitpc-video-2">Sample lessons</a></li>   
</ul>
<br/>
</p>


<div class="modal fade" id="flitpc-video-1">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content-vid">
         <div class="modal-body">
            <video id="flitpcdemo" controls autoplay width="100%">
               <source src="./video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="flitpc-video-2">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content-vid">
         <div class="modal-body">
            <video id="flitpcdemo" controls autoplay width="100%">
               <source src="./video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal-content-vid{
    background: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: And your JS code for closing pop up? I mean on which element you have binded event for closing popup

Comment: You are using bootsrap modal, as my answer below, you need to use each element structure. modal-content class in one of them which enable to click inside of it. So you need to add this class to element @BruceyBandit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootsrap modal has its own structure. So `modal-content` class is one of its element to make inside its content clickable so you need to add `modal-content` class

```js
$(function(){
    $('.modal').modal({
        show: false
    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        $(this).find('video')[0].pause();
    });
});
```

```css
.modal-content-vid{
    background: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h5>Explainer Videos</h5>
<p>Check out our videos below taken from one of our recorded webinars to see if this certification is right for you:
<ul class="nobullet">
<li><a style="text-decoration: underline; color:white;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#flitpc-video-1">See what our online course looks like</a></li>   
<li><a style="text-decoration: underline; color:white;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#flitpc-video-2">Sample lessons</a></li>   
</ul>
<br/>
</p>


<div class="modal fade" id="flitpc-video-1">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content modal-content-vid">
         <div class="modal-body">
            <video id="flitpcdemo" controls autoplay width="100%;z-index:100%">
               <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="flitpc-video-2">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content modal-content-vid">
         <div class="modal-body">
            <video id="flitpcdemo" controls autoplay width="100%">
               <source src="./video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
CSS:
```

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know model-content was already bootstrap related, I was watching a video tutorial and I decided to change that class to modal-content-vid myself. Cool, it works now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I do have one other question if you don't mind answering. If I close the modal, the video is still playing in the background. How can I stop and reset the video if the modal is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably the case of event bubbling

https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

In short what is happening is you click on video, but event bubbles and reaches to the parent element which has event which closes your popup
So you should stop bubbling,

like

```
<div class="modal-body" onclick=onModalBodyClick(event)>
    <video id="flitpcdemo" controls autoplay width="100%">
       <source src="./video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

And In JS

```
function onModalBodyClick(event) {
    event.stoppropagation();
}
```

Comment: Hi Kenny, the answer above helped but appreciate your answer also :)